# Excel to GDB field mapping and importing Excel data in geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, esri-geodatabase, excel, arctoolbox

I've got one Excel file which consists of data. I need to export that data to a gdb table. There are challenges. The gdb schema does not match with the Excel schema (I mean column names are different in excel and gdb table). I have to map each columns of the GDB with Excel.

I do not need to write the code.

I need myself if I can do it manually using the toolbox tools.

I am very new in Toolbox handling and arcpy as well.

Comment: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/importing-tables-importing-a-table-single-.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment from @AlexS1 mentioned [About importing tables](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/importing-tables-about-importing-tables.htm)

> You use the Table To Table and Table To Geodatabase tools to import dBASE, INFO, vector product format (VPF), OLE DB, or geodatabase tables into a geodatabase. These tools are available from the context senstive menu in the Catalog tree or from ArcToolbox.
>
> When you import several tables at the same time with the Table To Geodatabase tool, each table imports into a new table. The tool will automatically correct any illegal or duplicate field names.
>
> In your particular case [Importing a table (single)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/importing-tables-importing-a-table-single-.htm)
>
> In the Catalog tree, right-click the geodatabase into which you want to import a table. Click Import > Table (single).
>   This opens the Table To Table tool from the Conversion toolbox.
>
> Specify the following parameters for this tool:
>   Input Rows—Specify the input dBASE, INFO, OLE DB, or geodatabase table.
>   Output Location—Enter the location in which the output table will be created.
>   This can be either a geodatabase or folder. If the output location is a folder, the output will be a dBASE table.
>
> Output Table—Enter the name of the output table.
>   Expression (optional)—Enter the Structured Query Language (SQL) query expression that will be used to select records. The syntax for the expression is different for different data formats. Some of the most commonly encountered differences are below.
>   For ArcSDE, the field names are not wrapped, for example, MY_FIELD. For file or personal geodatabases, the field names are wrapped in square brackets, for example, [MY_FIELD]. For all others, the field names are wrapped in double quotes, for example, "MY_FIELD". Access uses * and ? as string wildcards rather than % and _ in all other formats.
>
> Field Map (optional)—Choose the fields and field contents from the inputs.
>   Each of the unique input fields is listed in the Field Map window, and when expanded, you can see a list of all the input field occurrences (subfields). New fields can also be added.For each field map, you can add, rename, or delete output fields as well as set properties such as data type and merge rule. You can also delete an output field's subfields, and you can format any output field's values if the data type is text.

Comment: Hello whyzar, Thanks for your detailed explanation. Just one thing which I observed want to share with you while mapping fields from excel to table. In case the Excel field has space in between the tool automatically converts the space with underscore (_). Is it the default tool behavior? and what is the field length it accepts in Field Map..